# SQL query return as grouped by primary keys

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

I need to select data from a table where there are 2 primary keys macid and deviceid.

I need the record set to group the records by these 2 primary keys but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is what I have now:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE stamp > 1373040000000 AND stamp < 1373126400000 ORDER BY macid ASC,deviceid ASC,stamp ASC

[
{"deviceid":1,"temp":-19.81,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373054400000},
{"deviceid":1,"temp":-20.31,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373065200000},
{"deviceid":3,"temp":28.87,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373054400000},
{"deviceid":3,"temp":28.87,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373065200000}
]
```

And this is what I needL

```
[
[{"deviceid":1,"temp":-19.81,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373054400000},
{"deviceid":1,"temp":-20.31,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373065200000}]

[{"deviceid":3,"temp":28.87,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373054400000},
{"deviceid":3,"temp":28.87,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373065200000}]
]
```

I have tried this but it just returns the same as the first results:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE stamp > 1373040000000 AND stamp < 1373126400000 GROUP BY macid, deviceid, stamp ORDER BY macid ASC,deviceid ASC,stamp ASC
```

Is this possible ??

Comment: Are you doing this via Python? And do you need the grouping to be done on the Python-side list?

Comment: Hi, I'm using javascript for this application. I would prefer for the recordset to return 2 separate records so that js cn then just loop through each mac/device group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't make SQL server return you multiple groups of rows. The **GROUP BY** statement is used to group rows by some columns and calculate aggregate functions for other columns (number of rows, sum, average, etc.). In result only one row for each group is returned.

So, I think we need approach here with grouping on the client side. You can do this as following:

```
var devices=[
{"deviceid":1,"temp":-19.81,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373054400000},
{"deviceid":1,"temp":-20.31,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373065200000},
{"deviceid":3,"temp":28.87,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373054400000},
{"deviceid":3,"temp":28.87,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373065200000}
];

var devicesGrouped = {};
for (i=0; i < devices.length; i++) 
{
   key = [devices[i].deviceid, devices[i].macid];
   if (!(key in devicesGrouped))
      devicesGrouped[key] = [];

   devicesGrouped[key].push(devices[i]);
}
```

The result will be `devicesGrouped` hash with `[deviceid,macid]` used as key:

```
{"1,19:5d:ee3e00":
     [{"deviceid":1,"temp":-19.81,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373054400000},
      {"deviceid":1,"temp":-20.31,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373065200000}],

 "3,19:5d:ee3e00":
     [{"deviceid":3,"temp":28.87,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373054400000},
      {"deviceid":3,"temp":28.87,"macid":"19:5d:ee3e00","stamp":1373065200000}]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution, much better than what I came up with.